Real numbers defined in ZFC vs real numbers defined using real closed field theory
Suddenly I came up with the notion of Real closed field theory which can also be used to define a version of real numbers.
I've learnt set theory and I know that the real numbers can be defined within ZFC set theory.
I'm confused here. Could you please explain me what is the difference between these "versions" of real numbers ? Will there be something is true for one version but false for the other ? And in normal mathematics, for example real analysis, it seems to me that the version defined within ZFC is normally used, why don't we use the version defined by using real closed field theory ?
Many thanks for your enlightment!

Real closed field theory is not a “definition” of real numbers. It is a logical theory, i.e., a set of axioms. The real numbers are one particular model of the theory, i.e., they satisfy the axioms. But they are not the only model. (For a start, real closed field theory is a first-order theory with an infinite model, so it automatically cannot be categorical, i.e., it cannot have a unique model, by Löwenheim-Skolem.)
Some interesting other models of real closed field theory are algebraic reals and computable reals. You can find more on the real closed field Wikipedia page.
On the other hand, within ZFC, we can write a formula which genuinely defines the set of real numbers (by using constructions such as Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts). Once the ambient universe of sets in which we are doing all mathematics is fixed, this defined the reals uniquely.
Edit: It is worth noting, as explained in the comments, that real closed fields other than the reals can have analytic properties that are very different from the reals. In particular, the algebraic reals and the computable reals do not have the least upper bound property of the reals (every non-empty set with an upper bound has a least upper bound). This makes, e.g., the intermediate value theorem fail for continuous functions from algebraic reals to algebraic reals or from computable reals to computable reals. They are not complete either (not every Cauchy sequence converges).

Hello, so maybe I should understand that ZFC and Real Closed Field theory indeed have nothing in common ? like the object of research of RCF is different from that of ZFC ? what do you think about it please ? Many thanks!

I don't understand the question. What is the “object of research” of a theory?

@VDT-QHH ZFC constructs a model of a real closed field. That is the relationship.

It might even be said to be the motivating model of a real closed field. @VDT-QHH

@JeanAbouSamra: Ah i mean that it seems that ZFC does care about the construction of real numbers whereas in RCF, it seems answer the question "given a set of objects, is it real closed field". Anyway, still, I am still confused why don't we use algebraic reals/computable reals as versions of real numbers in normal mathematics ? it seems to me that basically they have the same characteristics with real numbers defined in ZFC. Many thanks!

We also study algebraic and computable reals in normal mathematics, but separately from the set of all reals. There are many properties of real numbers that are not true in other real closed fields. For example, it is a basic and essential fact of real analysis that every set of reals with an upper bound has a least upper bound, but this holds neither for algebraic numbers nor for computable numbers.

You wrote it seems that ZFC does not care about the construction of real numbers. I don't know about ZFC, I've never asked it, but most human beings who are interested in mathematics are also quite interested in constructions and examples of objects that satisfy various sets of axioms: RCF axioms; group axioms; axioms of a topology; etc. And ZFC is a great tool for doing such constructions, whatever its personal feelings about being exploited for that purpose.

@JeanAbouSamra: Ah, I see. But is it surprised that 2 models (reals, algebraic reals) both satisfy axioms of RCF but eventually having different characteristics ? I think the common axioms must force them to have the same characteristics, right ? because we start with the same ground and use the same logical deduction...

No, it's not really surprising. For example, if you take the three axioms $∀ x, x \sim x$, $∀ x y, x \sim y ⇒ y \sim x$ and $∀ x y z, x \sim y ∧ y \sim z ⇒ x \sim z$, then the models are all sets with equivalence relations, of which there are very many. Said differently, the real closed field axioms are not precise enough to uniquely characterize the reals. But then, we know by Löwenheim-Skolem that no set of first-order axioms can uniquely characterize the reals.

@JeanAbouSamra: Hello, can you explain me why from the 3 axioms mentionned, you can conclude that the models are all sets with equivalence relations ? And by saying "equivalence relations", you mean equivalence relation between the models, right ? Thanks!!

The models are sets with equivalence relations just because the three axioms are precisely the usual axioms of an equivalence relation (reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity). And no, I mean that each model is a set equipped with an equivalence relation (the interpretation of $\sim$). I'm not talking about equivalence relations between different models.
